# How long would (dry) food in a glass jar survive in space?

Tags: space, food, radiation, vacuum

Say you eject a jar of jerky or something through the airlock of your space ship. Does the lid pop right away due to the vacuum? Does the food get so much UV it gives you cancer? (Does that depend on the type of food?) Is it likely to get hit by space dust at 17km/s and crack before it can stay for more than a few months?

(I found some related answers at
[Supplies sat in space for five years, are they still usable?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/183416/supplies-sat-in-space-for-five-years-are-they-still-usable)
claiming food would be edible, but I'm not sure if they assume the food is covered in something. [Cooking in the vacuum of space](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/87886/cooking-in-the-vacuum-of-space) assumes food is edible, but that's for a short period of time.)

Comment: This might be helpful to you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_drying

Comment: It would help quite a bit with the downvotes, I suspect, if you were to supply worldbuilding context.

Comment: food exposed to UV radiation for long periods of time will not give you cancer. Nor will the beef jerky develop cancer as its cells are already dead.

Comment: I should add a short item, not worthy of an answer. You can have your jerky sit open in the vacuum of space and be just fine. Expose it to the radiation of space and it will be just fine also, until its chemical properties break down and it is no longer nutritious and its consistency is more akin to dust.

Comment: Right. Irradiating food does *not* make it radioactive. It's actually a good way to *preserve* food [that is used in real life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food_irradiation). (Also, *jarred* jerky? I've only seen jerky in bags...)

Comment: But yes, the lid will pop, and your jerky dries out.

Comment: @Matthew Home-made jerky is often stored in glass jars.

Comment: A future spaceship along that route is destroyed by a spectacular collision with a jar-sized object containing the remnants of jerky. The object is far too massive for ship screens-or-armor designed to prevent damage from dust and sand grains and the occasional pebble. Lesson: Don't litter in space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Any packaging that has normal air pressure inside will burst or begin leaking immediately unless strong enough to survive in a vacuum, which would be uncommon.
- Any gas in the container is sucked away by the vacuum quickly.  After that, the moisture in the food also begins evaporating away through the process of [vacuum drying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_drying), along with any other volatile compounds.  What will be left of the jerky after a few days is probably bone dry, hard, and not very tasty.
- Assuming the container isn't exposed to sunlight in space, it will cool slowly, since vacuum is an insulator, through the process of [radiating away heat](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/72179/cooling-down-a-container-in-outer-space).  After some time, it will become extremely cold.  Alternatively, if the jar is in orbit where it is periodically exposed to sunlight, it will alternate between heating and cooling.  Either way, taste, nutrition, and texture is further degraded.
- The container, depending on what it is made of, may itself be subject to deterioration caused by accelerated [outgassing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outgassing) caused by vacuum and [photodegradation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photodegradation) from any sunlight exposure.  The outgassing may impart funky flavors to the jerky.
- Between being both dry as dust and frozen solid, bacterial growth on the jerky isn't going to be an issue.
- Radiation levels in space, outside of special environments, will not be high enough to cause any noticeable level of radioactivity in the food.